# Can't read newline from file

Tags: java

I want to read a file and remove all characters that isn't alphabetic, blank space and newlines.
And write that to a new file.

The problem with my code is that it isn't reading/writing newline. Alphabetic and blank space is working.

What can be the problem?

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("textfile.txt");

FileWriter newFile = new FileWriter("newtextfile.txt");

int value;

char c;

while ((value = file.read()) != -1) {
    c = (char) value;
    if (Character.isLetter(c) || c == '\n' || c == ' ')
        newFile.write(c);
    else
        newFile.write(' ');
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's Windows then you'd want to include `'\r'` as well.

Comment: I am using Mac OS

Comment: Tried it and it worked! What is '\r' ?

Comment: See [Wikipedia:Issues with different newline formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats)

Comment: You could also use [isWhiteSpace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) or [isSpaceChar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char)) instead of manually checking. Or use a regular expression and replace all characters you don't want to write.

Answer (score 0):

If your file uses Window-style line endings (as apparently it does), then you need to preserve carriage returns `\r` as well as line feeds `\n`.

See [Wikipedia:Issues with different newline formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats).

So add `'\r'` to the characters you are checking for.